# обработчики событий срабатывают одновременно?

Tags: c#, wpf

есть два обработчика событий -

```
private void Button_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
       Button btn= sender as Button;
        btn.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    private void Button_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = sender as Button;
        btn.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

которые "прицеплины" к одной кнопке

```
Button Background="White"
        Content="Menu"  DockPanel.Dock="Right" TextElement.FontSize="18" MouseEnter="Button_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Button_MouseLeave">
            <Button.LayoutTransform>
```

- т.е при наведении курсора показываем кнопку, когда курсор убран - прячем.
Но в итоге у меня получается, что когда курсор наведен на кнопку - эти два обработчика срабатывают одновременно - перекрывая действия друг друга и кнопка как бы "мигает". Из- за чего так происходит?

Comment: @Igor оформите лучше ответом

Comment: вопрос вызван опечаткой -> закрыть

Comment: ну и с какой радости его нужно закрывать?
Вот maxwell - дал полноценный ответ, который пригодится сообществу

Comment: Это не опечатка, а вполне нормальная проблема, которая неочевидна неопытным. Хотя, судя по тому, что я аналогичное встречал даже на ютубе, не всегда очевидно даже опытным))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Дело в том, что сейчас ваш код отрабатывает следующим образом:

1) При наведении курсора на кнопку срабатывает обработчик события `Button_MouseEnter`, где вы тут же скрываете кнопку:

`btn.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;`

2) Соответственно, так как кнопка скрылась, то начинает отрабатывать другой обработчик события `Button_MouseLeave`, где вы уже делаете кнопку видимой.

И так по кругу. Поэтому кнопка мигает.

---

Чтобы реализовать задуманное вам нужно сделать некий невидимый слой над кнопкой, который будет обрабатывать события `MouseEnter` и `MouseLeave`, т.к. если кнопка будет скрывать сама себя, то после того, как она станет `Hidden` событие `MouseEnter` не будет возникать.

Поэтому можно обернуть кнопку в `Border`, сделать его цвет прозрачным и обрабатывать нужные события.

XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Border Background="Transparent"
            MouseMove="Border_MouseEnter"
            MouseLeave="Border_MouseLeave"
            Margin="0,100">
        <Button x:Name="Button"
                Background="Red"
                Content="Menu" 
                Height="100"/>
    </Border>
</StackPanel>
```

Code-behind:

```
private void Border_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Button.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}

private void Border_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Button.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Button.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; - NullRefernceException, а если так
 (sender as Button).Visibility  = new Visibility();
то не могу обратиться к свойству - после конструктора.
Пробовал - отдельно создать экзепляр Visibility:
 Visibility pzz = new Visibility();
              (sender as Button).Visibility  =pzz. 
 - но там тоже не доступы свойства Visible и Hidden

Comment: @BadCats, вы дали имя баттону `x:Name="Button"` ?

Comment: да, теперь - работает, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

`Button_MouseEnter` выполняет действия, вызывающие `Button_MouseLeave`, - и наоборот.

Comment: Маловато как-то на ответ: даже в комментариях чуть ли не длиннее отписали ;) ;) ;)

Comment: @AK может быть - по количеству букв. Но какая концентрация мысли!

Comment: Вот только за неё и поставил плюс.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void Button_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   Button btn= sender as Button;
    btn.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; //<--
}

private void Button_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    btn.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden; //<--
}
```

Comment: На будущее: код -- это хорошо, но желательно ещё и пояснения приводить словами в ответе.